# Check Payment processor is not working for CIVIEVENT

Tags: civievent, payment-processor, registration, payment

I am having an issue with my Check Payment Processor. 
I am trying to setup the Check Payment method as a default payment processor for the registration of my events.

I have set only check as a payment processor. There is no other payment processor added yet. But when I try to register myself for the event, it asks me to add the credit/debit card option for the billing.

I have also set check payment as a default payment option.

[image: Payment Processor]

[image: Check Payment Settings]

[image: Test Drive view of the Event Registration]

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

If you need the payment through "Cheque" you don't need to enable payment processor -

All you need is to enable "is pay later" option in your event config page - Payment processor are used only when you do online payment using credit or debit cards.

So, disable your payment processor and select "is pay later" option and then give a try - that should work correctly

Refer: https://docs.civicrm.org/user/en/latest/events/creating-an-event/

I guess this helps !!!

Comment: This is the correct answer.